Entity Framework Core 6 loop and change tracker
I'm trying to avoid to call SaveChanges inside a loop and call it only once when the loop is completed.
Seems that in this case I have to SaveChanges at every iteration, here a small example.
I have these two entities:
public class OrderRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber {get; set; }
    public List<ShipmentRow> Rows { get; set; } 
}

public class ShipmentRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber {get; set; }
    public int? OrderRowId { get; set; }
    public OrderRow? OrderRow { get; set; }
}  

Now I need to match one or more rows of the shipment table with one order row, let's say this is the data inside the two tables.
OrderRows table:



Id
Part Number




111
A789


222
A789



ShipmentRow table:



Id
Part Number
OrderRowId




333
A789
null



In a loop I'm matching one row with the other (very simplified example).
In this example which OrderRow is matched to the ShipmentRow doesn't really matter, business logic is more complex but I simplified to avoid noise.
Let say that the first row that get used on the first iteration is the one that have to match with the ShipmentRow.
foreach (var item in dbContext.OrderRow.ToList())
{
    List<ShipmentRow> sRows = dbContext.ShipmentRow
                                       .Where(x => x.PartNumber == item.PartNumber 
                                                   && x.OrderRowId == null)
                                       .ToList();

    foreach (var s in sRows)
    {
        item.Rows.Add(s)
    }
    
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}

Result reflected on the ShipmentRow table:



Id
Part Number
OrderRowId




333
A789
111



Now I want to move SaveChanges() outside the loop and save everything at once, but the problem is that if I remove SaveChanges() from the loop in the second iteration sRows contains the already matched data because the database call seems to not be aware of the changes and OrderRowId is null.
This is what happen:

on the first iteration the shipment row with id 333 is retrieved and matched with order row id 111;
on the second iteration the shipment row 333 gets fetched and matched with order 222 *even though it should never be retrieved from the DB since it was already associated. The problem seems to be that the foreign key is not added to OrderRowId of ShipmentRow row with id 333 until SaveChanges is called.

I've tried adding it manually but the sRow database call still see the OrderRowId as null.
I'd like to move SaveChanges() outside the loop because is slowing things down too much.
I thought that EF Core was smart enough to detect that change, but it's probably me doing something wrong.
A possible solution: check if the shipment row retrieved from the database is already associated with the orders:
List<OrderRow> orders = dbContext.OrderRow.ToList();

foreach (var item in orders)
{
    List<ShipmentRow> sRows = dbContext.ShipmentRow
                                       .Where(x => x.PartNumber == item.PartNumber 
                                                   && x.OrderRowId == null)
                                       .ToList(); 
            
    foreach (var s in sRows)
    {
        if (orders.SelectMany(x => x.Rows).Any(x => x.Id == s.Id))
            continue;
        
        item.Rows.Add(s)
    }
}  

dbContext.SaveChanges();

Here is the ChatGPT solution: retrieve everything and work in RAM, could cause a large memory footprint when the database size increases:
var orderRows = dbContext.OrderRow.ToList();
var shipmentRows = dbContext.ShipmentRow.Where(x => x.OrderRowId == null).ToList();

foreach (var orderRow in orderRows)
{
    var matchingShipmentRows = shipmentRows
        .Where(x => x.PartNumber == orderRow.PartNumber && x.OrderRowId == null)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var shipmentRow in matchingShipmentRows)
    {
        orderRow.Rows.Add(shipmentRow);
        shipmentRow.OrderRowId = orderRow.Id;
    }
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();


Please add a [mcve] of what you are trying to do, something that can be executed and shows the problem you have. Also yourOrderRows table have multiple rows with the part number A789, which one should ShipmentRow.OrderRow point to? An ShipmentRow can only reference one OrderRow, but you use it like it can reference multiple OrderRow entries. Please [edit] your question with more detailed information.

@Progman I'm not seeing how I'm using it like ShipmentRow can have mutliple OrderRow, that's why I'm checking for OrderRowId == null for ShimpentRow database call.
If I use SaveChanges() on every iteration of OrderRow list I get the expected result: on second iteration no rows for ShipmentRow are returned so nothing can be matched because the only row that exists in the ShipmentRow table is already matched.

"I thought that EF Core was smart enough to detect that change" - there is nothing wrong with EF. Your ShipmentRow query looks in DB, not in DbContext. Nothing changed in the DB before SaveChanges, so EF is doing good work here. Also, your OrderRow can have multiple ShipmentRow's. How can you ship a single item in multiple shipments? You probably simplified the BL too much and removed some essential parts.

If your ShipmentRow table has multiple rows with OrderRowId = null and same Part Number, eventually, they all will have the same OrderRowId after the first iteration - 111. It means the OrderRowId = 222 has no chance of finding a matching ShipmentRow. I'm in doubt it was your intention. So, please fix your original code to do what you need, then we will be able to help you with a more efficient version.

@Artur
It means the OrderRowId = 222 has no chance of finding a matching ShipmentRow
That's indeed my intention, this is how I need it to work.
When a new ShipmentRow will get added to the database it could have the same PartNumber and so it will match with the OrderRow 222.

Then, when you retrieve the list of OrderRow just distinct it by PartNumber to not even try to match another order with the same part number.

@Artur thank you for clarifying that my query is actually looking in the database. I thought that it would first look in Local and if found return that instance, if not found return the database one.

AFAIK only Find method works like that.

Exactly!
I thought that my query would work that way, your initial comment clarified everything about where I was wrong. Thank you again.
